# Excel conditional formatting based on time values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Hi i need to create an Excel template like the cells will be loaded with a timestamp like

> `2014-09-29 16:02:59.112213`

I need to provide a condition like, if the timestamp is less than 3 AM, its color should be green, if it is between 3-4 AM it should be yellow and if exceeds 4AM, it should be red.

Please advise on the above requirements.

Comment: What specific part of Conditional Formatting are you having trouble with?  What have you already tried?

Comment: You mean same day between 12:00 AM to 3 AM = green, 3:01 AM to 4 AM = yellow, 4:01 AM To 11:59 PM = red?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with what is actually stored to code times.  Date/time values are stored as a number where the integer portion represents the number of days since a reference date and the fractional portion represents time as the decimal fraction of a day.  So, 3AM = 0.125, 4AM = 0.1666667 (enter as an explicit fraction, like 4/24 or 1/6, for precision).

You don't want any date information to affect your conditional formatting tests.  So, lets say your timestamp is in cell A1.  Use something like **mod(a1,1)** to provide the time portion of the value.

For conditional formatting, compare the time entries (i.e., **mod(cell-reference,1)** ) to those target time values.